# timed out message using python install command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, spacy

i am trying to install spacy '`en_core_web_md`' model but i get timed out message every time i try to download it using this python command :
'`python -m spacy download en_core_web_md`'

error message:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\r
equests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 237, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnecti
onPool(host='github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443)
: Read timed out.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `en_core_web_md` model is 115 MB, so depending on your internet connection (and GitHub's servers, where the models are hosted), it can always happen that the connection times out and the download fails.

You can also download the models via your browser or any other way that's convenient for you. You can find the `.tar.gz` archives in the individual [model releases](https://spacy.io/models/en) (just click the "Release details" button on the model you want to download). For example, [here's the `en_core_web_md` release](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_md-2.0.0).

Models are Python packages, so once you've downloaded the file, you can simply install it via pip:

```
pip install /path/to/en_core_web_md-2.0.0.tar.gz
```

You can then load it like this:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```